# Помогите реализовать поиск по тексту

Tags: python, поиск

В программе реализован поиск по listbox, но хотелось бы добавить поиск по тексту , и чтобы при нахождении слов из текста, показывало listbox в котором текст находится
Вот КОД

```py
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
def add_photo():
    cursor1 = connect("BD_Moscow_Enterta.db").cursor()
    if listbox1.curselection():
        selected_item = listbox1.get(listbox1.curselection())
        sql1 = 'UPDATE name_entertaiments SET photo = ? WHERE name = ?'
        data1 = []
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        with open(file_path, "rb") as F:
            image = F.read()
            data1.append((image,selected_item,))
        cursor1.executemany(sql1, data1)
        cursor1.connection.commit()
        cursor1.connection.close()
        show_photo(None)
def show_photo(event):
    selected_item = None
    if listbox1.curselection():
        selected_item = listbox1.get(listbox1.curselection())
    conn = connect('BD_Moscow_Enterta.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if selected_item:
        cursor.execute('SELECT photo FROM name_entertaiments WHERE name = ?', (selected_item,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            photo = result[0]
            if photo:
                image = Image.open(BytesIO(photo))
                image = image.resize((570, 510))
                photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
                label3.configure(image=photo_image)
                label3.image = photo_image
            else:
                label3.config(text="Изображение отсутствует")
                label3.config(image='')
                label3.image = None
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def save_text():
    text = text1.get('1.0', 'end')
    text = text.rstrip()
    if listbox1.curselection():
        selected_item = listbox1.get(listbox1.curselection())
        conn = connect('BD_Moscow_Enterta.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('UPDATE name_entertaiments SET text = ? WHERE name = ?', (text, selected_item))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
def show_text(event):
    selected_item = listbox1.get(listbox1.curselection())
    conn = connect('BD_Moscow_Enterta.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT text FROM name_entertaiments WHERE name = ?', (selected_item,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result:
        text = result[0]
        if text:
            text1.delete('1.0', 'end')
            text1.insert('end', text)
        else:
            text1.delete('1.0', 'end')
            text1.insert('end', "")
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
def show_photo_and_show_text(event):
    show_photo(event)
    show_text(event)
def window_add():
    global new_window
    new_window = Toplevel()
    new_window.title("Добавление места")
    new_window.geometry("300x150+700+300")
    label = Label(new_window, text="Введите имя места которое желаете добавить:",font="Arial 9 normal roman")
    label.place(x=14,y=15)
    entry1 = Entry(new_window,width=45)
    entry1.place(x=14,y=45)
    button1 = Button(new_window, text="Добавить", command=lambda: add_item(entry1))
    button1.place(x=115,y=80)
def add_item(entry):
    new_item = entry.get()
    if not new_item:
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Необходимо ввести значение")
        new_window.destroy()
        return
    if new_item in listbox1.get(0, END):
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Этот элемент уже есть в списке")
        new_window.destroy()
        return
    listbox1.insert(END, new_item)
    entry.delete(0, END)
    conn = connect('BD_Moscow_Enterta.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO name_entertaiments (name) VALUES (?)', (new_item,))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("Успешно!", "Значение было успешно добавлено!")
    new_window.destroy()
def delete_item():
    if not listbox1.curselection():
        messagebox.showerror("Ошибка!", "Необходимо выбрать элемент в списке!")
        return
    selected_item = listbox1.get(listbox1.curselection())
    listbox1.delete(listbox1.curselection())
    conn = connect('BD_Moscow_Enterta.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DELETE FROM name_entertaiments WHERE name = ?', (selected_item,))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    if listbox1.curselection():
        show_text(None)
    else:
        text1.delete('1.0', END)
        label3.config(text="Изображение отсутствует")
        label3.config(image='')
        label3.image = None
    messagebox.showinfo("Успешно!", "Значение было успешно удалено!")
def search_item(*args):
    query = search_var.get()
    if not query:
        listbox1.selection_clear(0, END)
        for i, item in enumerate(listbox1.get(0, END)):
            listbox1.selection_set(i)
    else:
        listbox1.selection_clear(0, END)
        for i, item in enumerate(listbox1.get(0, END)):
            if query.lower() in item.lower():
                listbox1.selection_set(i)
def toggle_search():
    if search_frame.winfo_ismapped():
        search_frame.place_forget()
    else:
        search_frame.place(x=0, y=16)
def open_modal():
    messagebox.showinfo("О программе", "База данных 'Известные места Москвы'\n (c) Юрков Д.В.,Россия,2023\nКонтактные данные:\nemail@mail.ru\n+7999999999")
def open_non_modal():
    non_modal = Toplevel()
    non_modal.geometry("350x150+700+300")
    non_modal.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    non_modal.title("Содержание")
    label1 = Label(non_modal,text="База данных 'Известные места Москвы'\nПозволяет: Добавлять/Изменять/Удалять информацию\nКлавиши программы:\nF1-Вызов содержания программы,\nF2-Добавление объекта в базу данных,\nF3-Удаления из базы данных,\nF4-Поиск,\nEscape-Выход из программы.")
    label1.place(x=5, y=5)
def KeyPress(k):
    if k.keysym=="Escape":
        if messagebox.askyesno("Выход","Вы точно хотите выйти?"):
            form1.quit()
    if k.keysym=="F4":
        open_non_modal()
    if k.keysym=="F1":
        window_add()
    if k.keysym=="F2":
        delete_item()
    if k.keysym=="F3":
        toggle_search()
    if k.keysym == "F5":
        open_modal()
        
cursor1=connect("BD_Moscow_Enterta.db").cursor()
cursor1.execute("SELECT name FROM name_entertaiments;")
rec2=cursor1.fetchall()
cursor1.connection.commit()
cursor1.connection.close()

form1=Tk()
form1.geometry("1280x600+200+100")
form1.title("Известные места Москвы")
form1.resizable(width=False, height=False)
label1=Label(bg="#5CCCCC").place(width=1280,height=36)
label2=Label(bg="#5CCCCC").place(width=1280,height=36,y=565)

listbox1=Listbox(width=40,height=300)
for row in rec2:
    listbox1.insert(END,row[0])
listbox1.pack(pady=35,anchor='w')
listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',show_photo_and_show_text)

label3=Label(text="Тут фото")
label3.place(x=532,y=300,anchor='center')

text1=Text()
text1.place(x=820,y=35,width=458,height=530)
text1.config(wrap="word",font="Arial 11 normal roman")

save_button = Button(text="Сохранить текст")
save_button.place(y=565,x=1179)
save_button.configure(command=save_text)

add_photo_button = Button(text="Добавить фото")
add_photo_button.place(y=565,x=470)
add_photo_button.configure(command=add_photo)

search_frame = Frame()
search_var = StringVar()
search_entry = Entry(search_frame, textvariable=search_var,width=40)
search_entry.grid()
search_var.trace("w", search_item)
search_frame.pack_forget()

menu0=Menu(form1)
form1.config(menu=menu0)

menu0.add_command(label="Добавить (F1)",command=window_add,font="Arial 11 normal roman")
menu0.add_command(label="Удалить (F2)",command=delete_item,font="Arial 11 normal roman")
menu0.add_command(label="Поиск (F3)",command=toggle_search,font="Arial 11 normal roman")

menu1=Menu(tearoff=False)
menu1.add_command(label="Содержание (F4)",command=open_non_modal,font="Arial 9 normal roman")
menu1.add_separator()
menu1.add_command(label="О программе (F5)", command=open_modal,font="Arial 9 normal roman")
menu1.add_command(label="Выход (ESC)", command=form1.quit,font="Arial 9 normal roman")
menu0.add_cascade(label="Справка",menu=menu1)

form1.bind("<KeyPress>",KeyPress)

form1.mainloop()
```